# Цитата в кавычках и со строчной?

Tags: прописная-строчная, цитата

> Как нередко пишут в старинных путеводителях о памятниках:
>
> **«был испорчен барокко».**

Спасёт ли меня запятая:

*Как нередко пишут в старинных путеводителях о памятниках, «был испорчен барокко».*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, оформление правильное.

http://videotutor-rusyaz.ru/uchenikam/teoriya/313-osnovnyesposobycitirovaniya.html

3. Предложениями с вводными словами.

Например: По словам А. М. Горького, «искусство должно облагораживать людей».